# Spring-boot security won't respect roles with custom AuthenticationProvider

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-starter

I am creating my own custom authentication provider. Right now i am just checking for a static username and password but later this will be replaced with something more advanced, so while i dont need to use a custom provider in this case that won't help me much since its just the ground work for additional code i havent added yet.

With that said this is my code in its broken state.

My custom authentication provider:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Component
public class SatAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SatAuthenticationProvider.class);

  public SatAuthenticationProvider() {
    LOGGER.info("*** CustomAuthenticationProvider created");
  }

  @Override
  public boolean supports(Class<? extends Object> authentication) {
    return (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication));
  }

  @Override
  public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

    LOGGER.info("*** Creating authentication");
    if (authentication.getName().equals("test") && authentication.getCredentials().equals("test")) {
      List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<>();
      grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"));
      grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ADMIN"));
      return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authentication.getName(), authentication.getCredentials(), grantedAuths);
    } else {
      return null;
    }

  }
}
```

Here is my security configuration that consumes is:

```
import com.comcast.iot.das.auth.SatAuthenticationProvider;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class DeviceSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SatAuthenticationProvider.class);

  @Autowired
  private SatAuthenticationProvider satAuthenticationProvider;

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    LOGGER.info("*** configuring http");
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest()
      .hasRole("USER")
      .and()
      .httpBasic();
  }

  @Autowired
  public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    LOGGER.info("*** Setting builder");
    auth.authenticationProvider(this.satAuthenticationProvider);
  }
}
```

Now when I run this if i use curl to hit an endpoint with no user and password specified I get the following:

```
% curl http://localhost:8080/molecule
{
  "timestamp" : 1505925047977,
  "status" : 401,
  "error" : "Unauthorized",
  "message" : "Full authentication is required to access this resource",
  "path" : "/molecule"
}
```

If I specify the correct username and password I get the following:

```
% curl -u test:test http://localhost:8080/molecule
{
  "timestamp" : 1505925033015,
  "status" : 403,
  "error" : "Forbidden",
  "message" : "Access is denied",
  "path" : "/molecule"
}
```

Finally if I specify the wrong username and password I get the following:

```
% curl -u test:test2 http://localhost:8080/molecule
{
  "timestamp" : 1505925199406,
  "status" : 401,
  "error" : "Unauthorized",
  "message" : "No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken",
  "path" : "/molecule"
}
```

One final point, while I cant get roles to work directly I can get it to test for if a user is authenticated at all and use it to give permission. This isnt a viable solution, as I need roles, but it may give anyone trying to answer this question some hints.

So I can change the DeviceSecurityConfig class's configure method as follows:

```
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    LOGGER.info("*** configuring http");
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest()
      .authenticated()
      .and()
      .httpBasic();
  }
```

With this new version of the code my curl requests do seem to at least work as expected (though there is no way to add roles in of course):. Here are the curl results with the code edit I just mentioned.

No username and password:

```
% curl http://localhost:8080/molecule
{
  "timestamp" : 1505925444957,
  "status" : 401,
  "error" : "Unauthorized",
  "message" : "Full authentication is required to access this resource",
  "path" : "/molecule"
}
```

Incorrect password:

```
% curl -u test:test2 http://localhost:8080/molecule
{
  "timestamp" : 1505925456018,
  "status" : 401,
  "error" : "Unauthorized",
  "message" : "No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken",
  "path" : "/molecule"
}
```

The correct password and username using the following command now returns the full response form the endpoint I'd usually expect (omitted).

```
% curl -u test:test http://localhost:8080/molecule
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Role authorities should be prefixed with `ROLE_`:

```
grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
```